# Add custom Parsley validation

Tags: validation, parsley.js, parsley

I have the following code. First zone is for telephone and second is for email validation. I'm trying to use Parsley library for validation.

The requirement is to validate at least one of it.
How should proceed for that.

Any pointers is appreciated.

```
<div class="row" data-parsley-required-if="" data-parsley-validate-if-empty="">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Guest Phone" data-mask="999-999-9999">
    </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" data-parsley-trigger="focusout change" placeholder="Guest Email">
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This example](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/custom-validator-events.html) does pretty much exactly that...